# How can one use the @Version annotation with an MVC application?

Tags: java, jpa, version

I've been looking into ways to prevent two users from thinking they were successfully modifying the same data at the same time. For example, if two users load an edit page and both users work on the edit page for a few minutes, if user A submits the form to save and then user B submits the form, the data in user B's form will win because it's updated in the database last. The problem here is that both users think their work was saved without any issue when user A's work is now lost.

I was hoping I could use the JPA [@Version](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html) annotation. I'd do this by keeping track of the version when the edit page is loaded and sending that version to the back-end when the form is submitted. The version coming from the front-end would be put in the version field on the entity loaded for updating and then we'd rely on JPA to prevent the save if the version doesn't match what's in the db. In the above case, user A would win and user B would get a message saying their save failed because the data had been updated by another user.

The problem here is that I've read in a few places now that the value that is being set in the field associated with the `@Version` annotation should not be edited manually. The question is: is this just a recommendation for normal use but my approach would actually work or is this something more fundamental and there are other reasons not to set the version field manually?

Our stack is an Angular front-end/Spring+JPA (Hibernate) back-end so keep in mind that all of the data exchange from the front-end to the back-end is over REST and we're converting Java objects to/from JSON. So, our typical edit/save round trip would look something like this:

1. Browser makes request for entity to be edited by ID
2. Back-end gets request, looks up entity using JPA, converts entity to JSON, sends to front-end in response.
3. Browser gets JSON from response, converts to object, draws and pre-populates form with data from object being edited.
4. User makes edits and submits form. Browser sends new request to back-end with JSON representing modified entity.
5. Back-end looks up entity using JPA, modifies it, and saves it using JPA.

To be clear, in step 5, if we use the `@Version` annotation and do not manually set it, the version will not have changed and we still have a problem where one user submitting the form will potentially overwrite another's changes. I'm suggesting the front-end keeps track of the version number, sends it back to the back-end with the edits and having the back-end setting the version number on the retrieved object in step 5. If this happens, wouldn't the save that is inadvertently overwriting the previous user's save fail?

Comment: `@Version` maintains the integrity of your data. It is not recommended to expose it to the front-end. If you really want to maintain the data concurrency, you can use a separate field(say revisions) and manage it.

Comment: Why do you need to set it manually?

Comment: I've updated my question with more details on what I'm proposing and why I think using @Version without manually modifying wouldn't work.